# Uncaught syntax error in fizz buzz code in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

Can't figure out my syntax error. From my reading it's expecting an end keyword?

I've include the rspec file that is testing my code in addition to the error statement and code. thanks any and all who help!

```
def fizzbuzz(int)
  if int % 3 == 0;
    puts "Fizz";
    if int % 5 == 0;
      puts "Buzz";
     if int % 3 && 5 == 0;
       puts "FizzBuzz"; 
end
```

RSPEC FILE:

```
require_relative './spec_helper.rb'

describe "fizzbuzz" do
  it 'returns "Fizz" when the number is divisible by 3' do
    fizz_3 = fizzbuzz(3)

    expect(fizz_3).to eq("Fizz")
  end
  it 'returns "Buzz" when the number is divisible by 5' do
    fizz_5 = fizzbuzz(5)

    expect(fizz_5).to eq("Buzz")
  end
  it 'returns "FizzBuzz" when the number is divisible by 3 and 5' do
    fizz_15 = fizzbuzz(15)

    expect(fizz_15).to eq("FizzBuzz")
  end
  it 'returns nil when the number is not divisible by 3 or 5' do
    fizz_4 = fizzbuzz(4)

    expect(fizz_4).to eq(nil)
  end
end
```

ERROR:

```
/Users/user/Development/code/rspec-fizzbuzz-001-prework-web/spec/spec_helper.rb:8:in `require_relative': /Users/user/Development/code/rspec-fizzbuzz-001-prework-web/fizzbuzz.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    from /Users/user/Development/code/rspec-fizzbuzz-001-prework-web/spec/spec_helper.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/Development/code/rspec-fizzbuzz-001-prework-web/spec/fizzbuzz_spec.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/user/Development/code/rspec-fizzbuzz-001-prework-web/spec/fizzbuzz_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `load'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: this is not _python_ :p

Comment: You have to terminate `if` statements with `end` in Ruby.

Comment: Just figured that out thanks Marek. Now I fixed that but for some reason the code is returning "Fizz" on the "FizzBuzz" section of code.

Comment: `if int % 3 && 5 == 0;`   you need to say `if int % 3 == 0 && int %5 == 0`

Comment: And checkout `if/elsif/end` and/or `case` statements for these scenarios.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is being downvoted. Yes it is basic, but it is well explained, and easily answerable.

Answer (score 0):

you need to terminate your if statements, this should fix the problem:

```
def fizzbuzz(int)
    if int % 3 == 0
        puts "Fizz"
    end
    if int % 5 == 0
        puts "Buzz"
    end
    if (int % 3 == 0) && (int % 5 == 0)
        puts "FizzBuzz"
    end
end
```

Comment: I think it'd be best to combine all your `if` statements together, and order them in a way so that they will return the results you want. For example, `int % 3 == 0` and `int % 3 == 0 && int % 5 == 0`. If you ordered the `if` statement in the current order, and `int = 15`, you will `puts "Fizz"`, then `puts "Buzz"`, and finally you will `puts "FizzBuzz"`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Any commentary on style, correctness, or coding quality are not relevant to this question.

Comment: If I add the puts all three fail.When I keep the return only the FIzzBuzz section fails.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
def fizzbuzz(int)
  if int % 3 == 0 && int % 5 == 0
    puts "FizzBuzz"
  elsif int % 3 == 0
    puts "Fizz"
  elsif int % 5 == 0
    puts "Buzz"
  end
end
```

This will output only 'FizzBuzz' if its a multiple of both, 'Fizz' for multiples of 3 only, and 'Buzz' for multiples of 5 only.